# Is the intersection of such a triple of minimal surfaces in the 3-ball a single point?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, minimal-surfaces

Let $S_1,S_2,S_3$ be three simple closed curves on the 2-sphere $\mathbb{S}^2$. (With no smoothness or rectifiability assumption)

For each $i$, let $M_i$ denote the minimal surface (i.e. disc) bounded by $S_i$, as provided by Douglas. Note that $M_i$ is contained in the interior of $\mathbb{S}^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Suppose that the intersections of the $S_i$ follow the same pattern as the intersections of the equator of the earth with two distinct Meridian circles; that is, $S_i \cap S_j$ is a pair of points for every $i \neq j$, and $S_i$ separates the two points of $S_{i+1} \cap S_{i+2}$ for every $i$, where addition is modulo 3.

> Question: Must $M_1 \cap M_2 \cap M_3$ be a single point?

Comment: Can you please provide a reference for the theorem of Douglas/Rado?

Comment: @DanielAsimov: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plateau%27s_problem. This is the classical problem of Plateau, for the solution of which Douglas was awarded one of the first Fields medals.

Comment: That is not a useful reference, since it does not provide the exact statement of the theorem.

Comment: @Agelos Are you sure that the Plateau problem is well-defined if you do not assume any sort of regularity of the curves, not even rectifiability?

Comment: @LeoMoos: Yes, the reference is [J. Douglas, SOLUTION OF THE PROBLEM OF PLATEAU](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1931-033-01/S0002-9947-1931-1501590-9/S0002-9947-1931-1501590-9.pdf). The second sentence reads "This memoir presents the first solution of this problem for the most general kind of contour: an arbitrary Jordan curve in n-dimensional euclidean space. " I'm removing the confusing reference to Rado in the question, as Rado assumed rectifiability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>This isn't an answer, but is too long for a comment.</s>

**Your question has a negative answer in general -- see below.**

One initial comment: There is no reason in general for there to be a unique Douglas-Rado disk (i.e. an area minimizer in the class of disks) so you can't really speak of "the the minimal surface (i.e. disc) bounded by $S_i$, as provided by Douglas."

That being said, there are, in general, also many other minimal disks spanning a curve that are not Douglas-Rado solutions (i.e. are not area minimizing disks but just minimal).

If you consider solutions of the latter type, your question is definitely false.

As an example: Consider $S_1$ to be the curve given by starting with the three parallel circles $\mathbb{S}^2\cap \{x_3=0, \pm \epsilon\}$ (for $\epsilon>0$ small) which we denote by $C_0$ and $C_{\pm \epsilon}$. Form $S_1$ by cutting out small pieces from the three circles around the intersection with the $x_1=0$ plane and then gluing in two "necks" connecting the three circles.  The one connecting $C_\epsilon$ and $C_0$ is on the $x_2>0$ side and the connecting $C_{0}$ and $C_{-\epsilon}$ is on the $x_2<0$ side.  This gives the curve $S_1$

By the [bridge principle](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01192091) for stable minimal surfaces as long as the necks are small enough there is a stable minimal disk, $M_1$, spanning $S_1$.  It looks like three stacked disks joined by small bridges.

For $S_2$ and $S_3$ take two small rotations around the $x_3$-axis of the circle $\{x_1=0\}\cap \mathbb{S}^2$.  If you choose the rotations properly (in particular small enough compared to the size of the necks used in constructing $S_1$) then the three curves satisfy your hypothesis.   In this case there are unique minimal disks $M_2$ and $M_3$ spanning $S_2$ and $S_3$ which are flat.  It is not hard to see that $M_1\cap M_2\cap M_3$ consists of three points.

This doesn't quite mean you can't solve your problem, but it does mean you have to use the area minimizing property.  Indeed, in this picture there should be at least two area-minizing disks spanning $S_1$ and for both the triple intersection should be a disk

**Edit:**

In fact, as pointed out by @LeoMoos, this construction can be turned into a counterexample to the original question.  The needed modification is as follows:

Pick $\epsilon\in (0,1)$ sufficiently large so any minimal surface spanning $C_0\cup C_{-\epsilon}\cup C_\epsilon$ has three components and hence is three disks.  Such an $\epsilon$ can be seen to exist by using catenoid barriers.  In particular, the area minimizer in the GMT sense (more formally the $\mathbb{Z}_2$-minimizing integral current) with this boundary is the union of the three flat disks.

It follows that in this case, if the necks are thin enough, then the Douglas-Rado solution with boudary $S_1$ looks like the three disks joined by thin bridges.  To see this just send the neck size to zero in this case $S_1$ converges as a $\mathbb{Z}_2$ current to the three circles which means $M_1$ converges as a $\mathbb{Z}_2$ current to the three disks.

The rest of the argument is the same.

Comment: This is a nice example! Could you explain why it's not possible to move the top and bottom circles apart (so increasing $\epsilon$) until the horizontal disks are area-minimizing, and then plugging in very thin necks? I don't know White's paper that well, but it seemed to say that if the necks are thin enough, there wouldn't be a 'gap' along the vertical axis, and you would retain the three intersection points. (I might have misunderstood something, though.)

Comment: Now that you mention it, I don't think there is any reason that this construction can't also produce an area minimizing disk (modulo checking some additional details).  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Good example, thanks! It seems to me that you can simplify it by starting with two discs connected with a neck instead of three. I realize that my question has been rather vague, as there can be several minimal discs as already pointed out. I was most interested in the unique area minimiser, which in my setup does exist; see e.g. [Coskunuzer --- GENERIC UNIQUENESS OF AREA MINIMIZING DISKS FOR EXTREME CURVES](https://www.jstor.org/stable/40864470). This example does answer my question.

Comment: @Agelos I don't think two circles can be made  to satisfy the hypothesis about how the curves intersect.  You can also arrange them to have zero points of intersection (in general I think for generic curves satisfying the hypothesis should, via a linking argument, have an odd number of intersection points).

Comment: @RBega2 How does the example with zero points go? I assumed it would have to be non-empty, maybe by an argument that could go as follows. Let $D_i$ be the three area-minimizing disks, and $\gamma_{ij} = D_i \cap D_j$. Concentrate on $D_1$ for example. Then $\gamma_{12},\gamma_{13} \subset D_1$ are curves with endpoints along $\partial D_1$; moreover they do not have self-intersections. By assumption $\gamma_{13}$ has one endpoint in one component of $D_1 \setminus \gamma_{12}$, and one in the other. Therefore $\gamma_{12}$ and $\gamma_{13}$ intersect (and the number of intersections [...]

Comment: [...] would be odd, provided one counts points where $\gamma_{12},\gamma_{13}$ meet tangentially with multiplicity.) That's just how I was thinking about this.

Comment: @LeoMoos If you just redo the original construction (with $\epsilon>0$ small) but only two circles and use the area minimizing disk, then you get a ribbon bounding $S_1$ that doesn't meet curve giving the intersection of the two other disks (which is a subset of the z-axis).   The stable disk bounding $S_1$ given by the bridge principle should intersect twice.

Comment: @RBega2 Ah, OK, I misread your comment: I thought you meant that under the given hypotheses there are examples with zero intersection.